# How to Inspecting and modifying variables in runtime using dwarf with GDB

Tags: c++, elf, plc, dwarf

Is the a possible way to read and modify the variable of C++ program in runtime without breakpoints using dwarf file with GDB?

I tried it but it look possible with breakpoints but i do not have to do it in that way because with simple reading is possible but i want a program with dwarflib as twincat and spyder show contents of variable in tun time.

Comment: Is it a non-`const` global variable? Perhaps it'd be best if you supplied [mre] containing a variable that you'd like to be able to change without setting breakpoints.